# Bug while using a hyperlink from HTML to upload file to SharePoint 2010 document library

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Utter newbie here, so please bear with me.

I'm building a small HTML based website (using the Bootstrap framework). I want to be able to upload files with some metadata to a SharePoint 2010 document library. Trouble is that when I link the "upload.aspx" form to my HTML page, I get a weird bug wherein the file that I upload starts downloading at the end of the process.

The "upload.aspx" works fine, but the next page "editform.aspx" is what throws this problem. Once I enter the metadata and click "OK", I get a prompt asking me to download the file. The file does, in fact, get uploaded with the metadata, but it's a bit frustrating from a user experience standpoint.

Is there another way to do this with just HTML/JavaScript? I did try to give it a shot with using the Content Editor webpart, but that messed up the styling. Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [SPServices Jquery Library for SharePoint Web Services](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Lists). There are a list of Supported Operations for this library which can be used. For your scenario, "AddAttachment" operation would be the one you are looking for.

```
$().SPServices({
            operation: "AddAttachment",                 
            listName: listName,
            asynch: false,
            listItemID:itemId,
            fileName: this.filename,
            attachment: data,
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {    
                console.log('attachment upload complete',xData,status);
            }
        });
```

Be sure to add the Name of the List and the ID of the item to which the file has to be attached. Feel free to comment if you have more questions.